# Boost Software License seems to extend disclaimer of warranty automatically but the author says it doesn't

Tags: licensing, mit-license, boost

Here is a copy of the Boost software license.

```
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or organization
obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying documentation covered by
this license (the "Software") to use, reproduce, display, distribute,
execute, and transmit the Software, and to prepare derivative works of the
Software, and to permit third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to
do so, all subject to the following:

The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement, including
the above license grant, this restriction and the following disclaimer,
must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and
all derivative works of the Software, unless such copies or derivative
works are solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by
a source language processor.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE
FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

The second paragraph of the license requires the warranty disclaimer to be retained in all copies of the software (except purely binary ones). Further, in the warranty disclaimer both "THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS" as well as "ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE" is protected from being liable for damages.

Here is a copy of the MIT license.

```
Copyright (C) <year> <copyright holders>

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

In contrast, the MIT license doesn't require the warranty disclaimer to be retained in all copies of the software and only the "THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS" are protected from being liable for damages.

It looks like the Boost Software License provides better protection against liabilities to anyone dealing with the software (even those who are simply distributing the software). Also, the Boost Software License makes it mandatory to reproduce the disclaimer in all copies.

Why then does the author of the Boost license mention in http://lists.opensource.org/pipermail/license-discuss_lists.opensource.org/2007-November/014828.html that the Boost license *"does not extend the disclaimer of warranties to licensees, so that they may, if they choose, undertake such warranties (e.g., in exchange for payment)"*?

Comment: I think it simply means that the licensee can buy a warranty if they so choose, or they can be granted a warranty by the licensor/distributor.  I do agree that the wording is a bit tricky, though; as a non-lawyer, I can't tell you which agreement (the license or the warranty) would take precedence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What you say holds true for MIT license as well. But at http://ideas.opensource.org/ticket/45 zak seems to imply that the Boost Software License does not extend the disclaimer of warranty to licensees while the MIT License does.

Comment: If anything, the reverse seems to be true.  The MIT license disclaims warranty for only the authors and the copyright holders, while the Boost license disclaims warranty for everyone except the consumer (who, since he's not distributing, doesn't need a disclaimer of warranty).

Comment: The URL doesn't seem to work. Can you update it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support for third-party products and services should be directed to the appropriate support channels.